# Django ORM - Error retreiving data -

Tags: python, django, sqlite, orm, python-3.5

I'm creating a page that has one video , as many comments , replies for each comment
I could retrieve video and comments but replies for each comment haven't been retrieved eventually.
I made some for loops in views file but didn't know also how to retrieve it in the templates file.
I'm stuck between views and templates till now

I'm using django 1.10.4

models.py

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    embed_code = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    free_preview = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    share_message = models.CharField(max_length=150, default=default_share_message)

    objects = models.Manager()
    # activemodel = ActiveModel()
    featuresandactive = Features()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'category')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        try:
            return reverse('video_detail', kwargs={'vid_slug':self.slug, 'cat_slug':self.category.slug})
        except:
            return "/"


class Comment(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, null=True, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    Timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    objects = CommentManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


class Reply(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment,null=True, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    Timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    objects = ReplyManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

views.py

```
def video_detail(request, cat_slug, vid_slug):

    cat = Category.objects.get(slug=cat_slug)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(video=obj)
    replys = Reply.objects.filter(comment=comments)

    context = {

    "cat": cat,
    "obj":obj,
    "comments":comments,
    "replys":replys,

    }
    return render(request, 'video_detail.html', context)
```

this is another view.py 
I tried this also but didn't work

```
def video_detail(request, cat_slug, vid_slug):

    cat = Category.objects.get(slug=cat_slug)

    obj = Video.objects.get(slug=vid_slug)

    comments = obj.comment_set.all()

    Replies = Reply.objects.filter(comment_id=comments.id))

    context = {

    "cat": cat,
    "obj":obj,
    "comments":comments,
    "replies":replies
    }
    return render(request, 'video_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ? What is the expected behavior, and if you are facing any ierror, etc what is it ?

Comment: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'...This is the first issue . it can be solved if i use for loop in the view. but how then I could get this data in template file.  I'm mainly trying to make a simple page like youtube video page. 1 video ..many comments. each comment has many replies

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you can represent the comments in your template. your template may look like this.

```
# your_template.html
{% for comment in obj.comment_set.all %}
    {{comment.user}}: {{comment.text}}
    {% for reply in comment.reply_set.all %}
        {{reply.user}}: {{reply.text}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

then your view function only needs `cat` and `obj`, not `comments` or `replies`. also check out [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't actually work. It couldn't parse any data.